# How to acces dict Python

Tags: python, dictionary

If I do `print(response["response"])` I get the code below but I only want to print each value of `"currency_code"` what do I need to do?

```
{
  "account_id": "2b9e9aea-59e4-11e9-8c75-0a0e6623f374",
  "balances": [
    {
      "account_id": "2b9e9aea-59e4-11e9-8c75-0a0e6623f374",
      "currency_code": "FEST",
      "change": "0.0",
      "available": "350.55778445",
      "locked": "0.0",
      "sequence": 8256,
      "time": "2020-01-15T17:35:04.435Z"
    },
    {
      "account_id": "2b9e9aea-59e4-11e9-8c75-0a0e6623f374",
      "currency_code": "BTC",
      "change": "0.0",
      "available": "0.000002444748",
      "locked": "0.0",
      "sequence": 8241,
      "time": "2020-01-14T23:30:12.570Z"
    },
    {
      "account_id": "2b9e9aea-59e4-11e9-8c75-0a0e6623f374",
      "currency_code": "ETH",
      "change": "0.3118",
      "available": "0.0",
      "locked": "0.0",
      "sequence": 8015,
      "time": "2020-01-13T06:59:06.443Z"
    },
    {
      "account_id": "2b9e9aea-59e4-11e9-8c75-0a0e6623f374",
      "currency_code": "EUR",
      "change": "35.96096",
      "available": "49.63897609",
      "locked": "0.0",
      "sequence": 8256,
      "time": "2020-01-15T17:35:04.435Z"
    },
    {
      "account_id": "2b9e9aea-59e4-11e9-8c75-0a0e6623f374",
      "currency_code": "MIOTA",
      "change": "15802.0",
      "available": "0.0",
      "locked": "0.0",
      "sequence": 8214,
      "time": "2020-01-14T23:00:11.357Z"
    },
    {
      "account_id": "2b9e9aea-59e4-11e9-8c75-0a0e6623f374",
      "currency_code": "BAN",
      "change": "1106.0",
      "available": "0.06758229",
      "locked": "0.0",
      "sequence": 7986,
      "time": "2020-01-08T11:53:27.266Z"
    },
    {
      "account_id": "2b9e9aea-59e4-11e9-8c75-0a0e6623f374",
      "currency_code": "XRP",
      "change": "14157.0",
      "available": "0.0",
      "locked": "0.0",
      "sequence": 8238,
      "time": "2020-01-14T23:30:07.002Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Do something like this: `for balance in response['response']['balances']: print(balance['currency_code'])`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pull out each element from the nested dictionaries, then iterate over the list of dictionaries and print the currency code:

```
for bal in response.get('response').get('balances'):
    print(bal.get('currency_code', ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for my_dict in response['responses']["balances"]:
  print(my_dict['currency_code'])
```

Comment: I get this error ```for my_dict in response['response']["balances"]:
TypeError: string indices must be integers```

Comment: I forgot to fully copy and paste the print statement, my bad print(my_dict['currency_code'])